# How to make one type list of tupel items?

Tags: c#, list, tuples

My List is this

```
List<Tuple<int, double, string>> multiValueList;
```

make use of multiValueList and I want make to
`List<Tuple<int, double>>` type list or `List<string>` type List.

what should I do?

Comment: Add the language tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a couple of simple LINQ expressions:

```
// List<Tuple<int, double>>
var list1 = multiValueList.Select(t=>Tuple.Create(t.Item1, t.Item2)).ToList();

// List<string>
var list2 = multiValueList.Select(t=>t.Item3).ToList();
```